# Clear plots generated by ipywidgets.observe

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have an ipywidget that generates a plot each time the selection changes. Currently the plots are appended to each other; however, I would like to have only *one* plot (the latest).

```
import ipywidgets as widgets 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(change):
    if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
        plt.close('all')  # seems to have no effect
        plt.plot([0, 1],[0, 10])
        plt.title(change['new'])
        plt.show()

w = widgets.Select(options=[0, 1])
w.observe(f)
display(w)
```

I tried without success:

- [using plt.close('all')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853801/how-do-i-close-all-pyplot-windows-including-ones-from-previous-script-execution)
- [splitting the code into two cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220626/ipywidgets-matplotlib-cannot-clear-old-outputs) (even if this seems not practical for the real application)

Note: I'm not using `interactive` since [I do not want to run all functions when any parameter changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260247/python-ipywidgets-how-to-find-out-which-parameter-changed-when-running-interac).

Comment: This is https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1919, see my comment there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending your charts to an `Output` widget, which can be used as a context manager, and then cleared with `out.clear_output()`.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
out = widgets.Output(layout = widgets.Layout(height='300px'))

def f(change):
    if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
        with out:
            plt.plot([0, 1],[0, 10])
            plt.title(change['new'])
            out.clear_output()
            plt.show()

w = widgets.Select(options=[0, 1])
w.observe(f)
display(w)
display(out)
```

Comment: Adapted this code to add a comment to https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1919#issuecomment-709917932